# Wordpress with datepicker

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

Here [myrussiaonline](http://pp.myrussiaonline.com/)

on my website you can see form under top slider. There are first input with id datepicker. So i need to call datepicker here in this input, but it's not working.
In functions php included:

```
    <?php
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
?>
```

In footer:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});
```

my input:

```
<input id="datepicker" style="height:15px;border:0; border-radius:0; width: 90px; position:relative;left: 50px; top: 31px; background: #E8E8E8; color: black;" type="text" name="datepicker" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
```

Also i checked ui core and css files and also datepicker.min.js loaded on my website, but I don't have reaction from my input. It's still ignoring date picking. So what's I do wrong?

Comment: validate your page html here http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Comment: Just validate. But I don't know how it will help to solve my problem

Comment: I suggest that you fix the google maps issue . it might not be related but since it is `javascript` you can never be too cautious.  javascript problems are chained ..

Comment: Also, i am not sure , but i think the `nicescroll`.js on your theme creates some problems ( at least on my firebug console )

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add script in action `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Please refer below code:

```
function my_theme_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_script');
```